# Save pictures in document using Powershell and Word 2013

Tags: html, image, powershell, rtf, word-2013

I'm trying to convert a HTML file with externally linked images to RTF using MS Word 2013 via Powershell commands, when using below command file gets converted however pictures are missing

```
$wrd = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$doc = $wrd.Documents.Open('c:\test.html')
$opt = [ref][Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::WdFormatRTF
$name= [ref]'C:\test.rtf'
$wrd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs($name, $opt)
$wrd.ActiveDocument.Close()
$wrd.Quit()
```

If I do the conversion manually by opening the HTML file with Word and saving it as RTF same thing happens, no images, however if within Word I go to File, click on "Edit Links to File" and highlight all images, tick "Save picture in document" and then click on "Break Link" and then do the save as RTF, this time images are present within RTF (however with bad quality which is another issue..) [See picture below]
[image]

Is there a way to execute above process within Powershell?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job

```
    $images = $doc.InlineShapes
    foreach ($image in $images) {
      $linkFormat = $image.LinkFormat
      $linkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = 1
      $linkFormat.BreakLink()
    }
```